# How can i convert number like 17 to be shown aa 17 asterisks -formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have exercise where i have ages like 8, 17, 29 etc, and 30 is the largest nr. I need a formula where the age is shown as asterisks such as if i have age 16 then it shows 16 asterisks ****************.

I tried so many things and didnt get even close. I tried getting the lenght with len so if its longer than 1 len then it should be 10-30 asterisks.
So if the lenght is bigger than one, then ill look whats the first number, if its 2 then ill print 20 asterisjs, if false sych as its three then ill print 30 and then ill see whats the next number after the first one. But it doesnt make sense to me how to write the formula.
It should be beginners exercise so i dont know how difficult the formula can ir is gonna be. Im so lost

Comment: Or [google your problem](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/repeat-a-character-in-a-cell-2a625cda-a177-4285-bca0-7c2f96d3088c) and voila, a formula solution.

Answer (score 2):

Plain and simple, use `REPT`:

```
=REPT("*",A1)
```

Result:

[image]